# unable to enable custom module in Magento ver. 2.0.0-rc

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.0

I have created custom module in `Magento ver. 2.0.0-rc` and I'm trying to enable by using below commands.

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Learning_Custom
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But it's not enabling. If I missing any other commands to activate module please let me know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check steps how to create Magento2 module http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html   and be sure you have registered your module http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/component-registration.html